# Unable to edit items on a webpage. Error: Determine composite primary key ordering for type Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to edit items on a webpage however I keep getting this error message: Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type 'com.twcl.it.isms.Models.Issue'. Use the ColumnAttribute (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386388) or the HasKey method (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386387) to specify an order for composite primary keys. I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the error. In the database line number is used as a composite key.

Update 
I'm now getting this error: EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
SelectListItems: EntityType: EntitySet 'SelectListItems' is based on type 'SelectListItem' that has no keys defined.; Not sure what else I should be adding

```
 [Key]

    public int lineNum { get; set; }
```

View

```
 if (@Model.items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var issueditem in @Model.items)
                            {
                                <tr>

                                    <td class="col-md-4">@issueditem.itemNumber</td>
                                    <td class="col-md-4">@issueditem.description</td>
                                    <td class="col-md-4">@issueditem.expense_account.getDescription</td>
                                    <td class="col-md-2">@issueditem.quantity.ToString()</td>
                                    <td class="col-md-2">@issueditem.quantityI.ToString()</td>
                                    <td class="col-md-1">@issueditem.selecteduomtext </td>
                                    <td class="col-md-1">@issueditem.price.ToString()</td>


                                    <td> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = issueditem.lineNum}) </td>


                                </tr>
                            }

                        }
```

Controller

```
      public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {

        Issue getIssue = db.Issues.Find(id);

        return View(getIssue);


    }

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Issue issue)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)

        {

            db.Entry(issue).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("IssueItem", issue);
        }


        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please make sure you have filled in all required fields.");
        }

            return View(issue);


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

a `Composite Key` means to use a combination of multiple properties as the key of an entity, in such case Entity Framework need to know the order of the key properties. As suggested in the exception message, you could use the `ColumnAttribute` to do so like:

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 1)]
public int key1 { get; set; }

[Key]
[Column(Order = 2)]
public string key2 { get; set; }
```

If you want to use only the `lineNum` as primary key, please check your model and make sure there is no other property has been applied with the `[Key]` attribute

Comment: I'm getting this error now: com.twcl.it.isms.Models.Data.SelectListItem: : EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
SelectListItems: EntityType: EntitySet 'SelectListItems' is based on type 'SelectListItem' that has no keys defined